# Command line, problems after the last windows update (1903)

Tags: weka

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VJbm.jpg)It has always worked but now it has stopped.
Maybe there is a problem with java path. 
I tried various solutions but I couldn't.
The problem emerged after formatting and reinstalling windows 10.
Without the command line everything works regularly

I installed weka 3.8(weka-3-8-3jre-x64.exe; 120.3 MB) on a new factory PC.(1903)
Same problem

thanks a lot

Comment: Is the typo in your classpath "%CLASPATH%" accidental?

Comment: to remove the doubt I tried in a new pc, with clean installation

Answer (score 0):

After your Windows/Weka reinstall, did you also reinstall the Weka package for libsvm?

Answer (score 0):

See parallel discussion on the Weka mailing list:

https://list.waikato.ac.nz/hyperkitty/list/wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz/thread/NSLPULS7EWNJDIJAH452S67CAHMJ5RGJ/